# In how far can a source term influence the propagation speed of an EM wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, speed-of-light

Unfortunately, I can only find discussions of signal speed for solutions of the *homogeneous* EM wave equations (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.2402.pdf).

Therefore, let me ask here: Can the form of the source affect the signal speed of a wave? Heuristically speaking, I cannot for instance imagine that the actual propagation speed of a wave could depend on the exact inner workings of an antenna...

I would be grateful for any mathematically more rigorous underpinning of my own heuristics, or of course counter-heuristics.

Comment: What do you mean by "signal speed" and "propagation speed"? Do you mean phase velocity, group velocity, or something different than either of those?

Comment: Thanks. Signal speed/propagation speed in the sense of the front ``velocity".

Comment: Also, can you list a reference to a "discussion of signal speed for solutions of the homogeneous EM equation"?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of EM waves in vacuum, when measured locally is always c. This does not depend on the source.

The speed of EM waves in denser media might be slower then c, when measured locally, but that (the fact that because of the denser media it will be less then c) does not depend on the source either.

This is true for Gravitational waves too. Any particle, with no rest mass, will travel at this speed in vacuum, when measured locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would also think that the source does not affect the propagation speed (properly speaking the front velocity of the wave) but how to justify this?